# Is it possible to link to the source code of git when I just remove the main function?

Tags: c, git, dynamic-linking

I want to write a GUI front-end for git in C. I know I can just pack a compiled binary of git within my application bundle (Mac OS X), but is it also possible to compile git as a dynamic library with just the main function removed (i.e. not compile git.c), and link to it?

---

Also, the license reads:

> b) You must cause any work that you distribute or publish, that in
>       whole or in part contains or is derived from the Program or any
>       part thereof, to be licensed as a whole at no charge to all third
>       parties under the terms of this License.

Does this mean I must release my app as GPL too, or only when I statically link it?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/), which is also released under a more permissive license.